# AWS EFS and Windows (yet again)

Tags: windows-server, amazon-efs

Restarting a topic I found here, a few years back: need to migrate a large pool of NFS shares / mount points content, used equally by Windows and Linux clients, from on-prem, to AWS. I looked at the official EFS page @ AWS, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/AmazonEFS.html), and there still doesn't seem to provide "support" for Windows instances. On the other hand, as few mentioned a few years back the UMIch NFS client ver 4.1 for Windows, that is already [what I assume to be] a new version available officially from Microsoft, supporting Server 2012, 2016, etc. Is Microsoft client still lacking what the UMich client offers, in order to work with the AWS EFS?